# How to make multiple criterias in an if statement

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I was wondering if I could get some help to make my `if` statements more compact. For example making these if-statements into one if possible with using `&&` or something. The different buttons have different values.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
if(ae.getSource() == button[0])                 
    display.append("7");                         
if(ae.getSource() == button[1])
    display.append("8");
if(ae.getSource() == button[2])
    display.append("9");
 }
```

Comment: `switch case` has been designed for the same purpose.

Comment: Can `button[x]` and `button[y]` contain the same value? If they do, do you want to do **both** operations? (For instance, `clear` and `getSqrt`?)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: `case` labels have to be constant values.

Comment: Consider having a different action listener for each button.

Comment: http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/java_conditional_statement.htm

Comment: Every `if` tests a different condition and takes a different action, so there's no way to combine them any further.  Maybe you could run each `if` and its associated then-statement together on one line, but you're not going to get any more compact than that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using one event handler for different buttons. I'd suggest to split these.

However, if you want more compact code with your current approach, you could use Kotlin (can be mixed with Java in the same project):

```
when (ae.getSource()) {
  button[14] -> clear()
  button[15] -> getSqrt()
  button[16] -> getPosNeg()
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with Kotlin?

Comment: Introducing another language just for compacting some `if`s seems overkill to me

Comment: @QBrute If you would introduce Kotlin only for if statements, I'd agree. But Kotline improves productivity (and developer happiness) in many other areas, too. More compact if statements would only be a special case of that.